# SQL server: How the behavior of SQL when WHERE by parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one statement like this:

```
DECLARE @parameter1 BIT = 0;
SELECT A.Filed1, A.Field2 FROM tblA A WHERE @parameter1 = 1;
```

I find some information in google, some people said that: because @parameter1 is a variable test, SQL Server does it first and aborts the entire part of SELECT if not true

BUT when I do the execution plan, I saw that the cost of scan table is 99%, and filter take 1%. It means SQL server still scan all rows of table though no result.

### What's right understand for this?

I mention this, because actually I have one situation like this:

```
DECLARE @parameter1 BIT = 0;
SELECT A.Filed1, A.Field2 FROM tblA A 
UNION 
SELECT B.Filed1, B.Field2 FROM tblB B
UNION 
SELECT C.Filed1, C.Field2 FROM tblC C WHERE @parameter1 = 1;
```

My purpose is: if @parameter1 = 0, we will not execute the query `SELECT C.Filed1, C.Field2 FROM tblC C`

I don't  want use IF statement to check @parameter1 like this:

```
IF (@parameter1 = 1)
BEGIN
   SELECT A.Filed1, A.Field2 FROM tblA A 
   UNION 
   SELECT B.Filed1, B.Field2 FROM tblB B
   UNION 
   SELECT C.Filed1, C.Field2 FROM tblC C
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   SELECT A.Filed1, A.Field2 FROM tblA A 
   UNION 
   SELECT B.Filed1, B.Field2 FROM tblB B
END
```

It gives some code duplicate and make the query longer.

Can anyone explain the behavior of SQL server as my situation? And give one best solution for my situation?

Thank in advance.
Lam

Comment: When you got the execution plan, did you get the estimated execution plan or the actual execution plan?

Comment: @Andrew: I have done both of estimate execution plan and actual execution plan. It has given same result: scan table takes 99%, filter takes 1%.

Comment: version of SQL Server? service packs/ cumulative updates?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: SQL2008 R2

Comment: BTW, your above query is already fine and it should be working.It is similar to mine .No need of If else.what is the actual problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are rather small, this execution plan may not result in poor performance.  After all, 99% of an insignificant query cost is still an insignificant query cost.

That said, depending on the structure of the table, there are a number of things you can try.  First, do you need `UNION`, or will `UNION ALL` suffice?  `UNION` removes duplicates -- `UNION ALL` does not, and it is typically faster as a result.

One possibility is to use a table variable:

```
DECLARE @TabVar TABLE
(
    [Field1] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [Field2] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([Field1], [Field2])
}

IF @Parameter = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT @TabVar ([Field1], [Field2])
    SELECT DISTINCT C.Field1, C.Field2
    FROM   tblC C
END

SELECT A.Field1, A.Field2
FROM   tblA A
UNION
SELECT B.Field1, B.Field2
FROM   tblB B
UNION
SELECT T.Field1, T.Field2
FROM   @TabVar T
```

There are certainly other possibilities, depending more on your specific situation.

Comment: Thank for your solution.
I think that insert into temp table solves my case fine. And it makes sure that the query SELECT ... FROM tblC will not execute when @parameter1 = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it already working.
@Jack purpose is when @parameter1=0, tblC should not fire.
oh thanks @Mitch,@flg is not require.
try this,

```
DECLARE @parameter1 BIT ;


SELECT A.Filed1, A.Field2 FROM tblA A 
UNION 
SELECT B.Filed1, B.Field2 FROM tblB B
UNION 
SELECT C.Filed1, C.Field2 FROM tblC C WHERE @parameter1 = 1
```

I have correct it now .